# tagged (802.1q) traffic and vmware workstation on linux

Tags: linux, networking, vmware-workstation, vlan

I am trying to bridge vmware workstation's VM NIC to tap interface on host that includes 802.1q/tagged (vlan) traffic. Somehow vmware bridging strips 802.1q header and all traffic gets to VM untagged. When running tcpdump on tap interface on host I see 802.1q headers, but when running tcpdump on VM's NIC inside vmware I don't. If I create two VMs inside vmware workstation, both bridged to same host NIC/tap interface - tagged(vlan) traffic is working between them, but not with outside world (host). I am running vmware workstation 9.0.2 build-1031769 on linux, kernel 3.10.11. Is this normal behaviors for vmware workstation? Is there any other workaround to get 802.1q traffic in VMs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found three workarounds

1. Patching `vmnet` modules (not working always) - see http://tnt.aufbix.org/vmware/workstation#using-vlans
2. Use GRE tunnel with 'gretap' - see http://tnt.aufbix.org/linux/network-tunneling#gre-tunnel-with-gretap / in guest VM you might have problems combing VLANs
3. Use `openvswitch` on host and guest VM and crate GRE tunnel between both openvswitches *(best option so far if you can run openvswitch in guest VM)*